# Mule cxf client and wcf service interaction

Tags: web-services, wcf, mule, esb

I have the workflow like

```
<flow name="testmulewcfFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/GetData" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.value]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-client port="CXFWebservicePort" operation="GetData" serviceClass="com.mulesoft.wcfconsumer.IService1" doc:name="CXF"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
</flow>
```

And very simple wcf service which I want to use from mule anypoint studio

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(string value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
```

But I when I make a call: http://localhost:8081/GetData?value=hello
I get the error:
*Unexpected wrapper element {http://tempuri.org/}GetData found.   Expected {http://tempuri.org/}GetDataResponse.. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PushbackInputStream*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That issue you are facing due to not implementing an outbound endpoint at the end after `cxf:jaxws-client`
Put an out bound endpoint at the end that will call your external web service with a `http:request` component :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Connector

Comment: I inserted <http:request  config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" @Anirban path="GetData" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/> and have "Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[]" Do I need to put any converters after the payload?

Comment: You can try with Byte to String transformer and check if it works